# Redmi 3s Prime stuck on logo (Not Rooted!)

Tags: xiaomi, mi, redmi

Redmi 3s Prime is stuck on Mi Logo (My phone is not rooted I haven't tried flashing anything at all).

Another strange thing is When I am calling from other mobile call is getting placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to recovery mode by pressing <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume up</kbd>  then selected recovery mode. Pressed blue button (It was written in Chinese)  selected reboot to system it booted normally.